# How to refresh server files with python script that runs on server via remote browser?

Tags: python, php, html

I have a python script that refreshes html files on a server but I don't know how to make it run from a remote client browser. CGI seems to want to echo html back to client. I am not passing any data back to client except a message to refresh page. Script runs well in bash but does not execute from client browser.
I want client to click button that will launch script on server then refresh the client page(no physical or shell access to server). Is this possible?

The client displays the current data fine and when I update from server shell but I cannot update the data from a client. I am new to webpage and php stuff but am an old retired programmer so please, be gentle. (This is a personal, non-commercial project) I am trying to avoid a cron job which would be simplest solution but prog uses lots of network access and doesn't need to be up-to-date all the time.

Thanks in advance for your time...

What I have tried: php exec() call
Common to both:

```
`    <!DOCTYPE html>`
`    <html lang="en">`
`    <head>`
`        <meta content='width=device-width' name='viewport'/>`
`        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>`
'        <meta content='blogger' name='generator'/>'
'    </head>'

'    <form name="update" method=post>'
'        <button name = "update" type="submit"> Update blogs </button>'
'    </form>'
'    <?PHP exec("./cgi-bin/prog.py") (full path, file in Apache2 root also)'

'    <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="http://192.168.1.180/cgi-bin/prog.cgi"> (it is a python script)'
'    <form name="update" method=post="https://192.168.1.180/cgi-bin/prog.cgi">'
'        <button name = "update" type="submit"> Update blogs </button>'
'    </form> (Examples of this works if echoing html back to client)'
```

I did not expect anything to happen on the client side until the page refreshes. On the server prog.py should update some files on the server which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I came up with. If you have a better answer I would like to hear it.
I put a link to a refresh.php file that contained:

```
    `<?PHP 
    echo shell_exec("/var/www/html/prog.py");
    header("refresh: 1; 
           url=http://Mywebserver/index.php");
    ?>`
```

The link in index.php(generated by prog.py):

```
`<p><a href="refresh.php">update
(lastupdated=Thu, 11/Jan/2024,21:46:55)</a></p>`
```